# Mutate a column in a tsibble dataframe, applying a Box-Cox transformation

Tags: r, time-series, forecast, tsibble, fable

I am a big fan of Hyndman's packages, but stumbled with Box-Cox transformation.

I have a dataframe

```
class(chicago_sales)
[1] "tbl_ts"     "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I am trying to mutate an extra column, where the `Mean_price` variable will be transformed.

```
foo <- chicago_sales %>% 
mutate(bc = BoxCox(x = chicago_sales$Median_price, lambda = 
BoxCox.lambda(chicago_sales$Median_price)))
```

gives me some result (probably wrong too) and cannot apply `autoplot`.

I also tried to apply the code from [Hyndman's book](https://otexts.com/fpp3/transformations.html), but failed.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**UPDATED:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue, inside tsibbles, when using dplyr, you do not call `chicago_sales$Median_price`, but just `Median_price`. When using tsibbles I would advice using fable and fabletools, but if you are using forecast, it should work like this:

```
library(tsibble)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

pedestrian %>% 
  mutate(bc = BoxCox(Count, BoxCox.lambda(Count)))
# A tsibble: 66,037 x 6 [1h] <Australia/Melbourne>
# Key:       Sensor [4]
   Sensor         Date_Time           Date        Time Count    bc
   <chr>          <dttm>              <date>     <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2015-01-01     0  1630 11.3 
 2 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 01:00:00 2015-01-01     1   826  9.87
 3 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 02:00:00 2015-01-01     2   567  9.10
 4 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 03:00:00 2015-01-01     3   264  7.65
 5 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 04:00:00 2015-01-01     4   139  6.52
 6 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 05:00:00 2015-01-01     5    77  5.54
 7 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 06:00:00 2015-01-01     6    44  4.67
 8 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 07:00:00 2015-01-01     7    56  5.04
 9 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 08:00:00 2015-01-01     8   113  6.17
10 Birrarung Marr 2015-01-01 09:00:00 2015-01-01     9   166  6.82
# ... with 66,027 more rows
```

I used a built in dataset from the `tsibble` package as you did not provide a dput of `chicago_sales`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did this, but the numbers really scared me a lot. Please see my print screen. I thought it was too high.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker, Check the lamba. It looks as if it is too high. Check with `BoxCox.lambda(chicago_sales$Median_price)` to see what lambda it is using. For the example I used the lambda returns 0.108. But looking at your result it is closer to 2, which would result in a lot higher values in the bc transformation. If you check the [forecasting book version 2](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html), you can see how bc is used with forecast.

Comment: my lambda is 1.484661. I checked all possible resources and not sure what is wrong. My data has a very strong seasonal trend